# error on compiling biblatex

Tags: biblatex

why doesn't this work?

I run this on two different computers!

I saved the file "Ref.bib" in the same ".tx" file directory

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{faul2009statistical} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Error messages:

> ```
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file texstudio_So6416.aux
>
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file texstudio_So6416.aux
>
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file texstudio_So6416.aux
> ```

Comment: what error did you get

Comment: You have to run the external tool `biber` instead of `BibTeX`. Please see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Looks like texstudio compiles a not saved version of your tex file. Try to save it in a directory of your choice prior to compiling.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397584/problem-inserting-bibliography-in-texstudio/398100#398100

Comment: This could be a combination of the issues mentioned by Johannes_B and samcarter. You are definitely running the wrong bibliography tool: You need Biber and not BibTeX, Johannes' link tells you how to deal with that. But the file name hints at the issue mentioned by samcarter as well.

Comment: But shouldn't biblatex work with BibTex? If biblatex has the option backend=biber, it means working with biber is an option, not mandatory, right?

Comment: @user118967 - The option `backend=biber` is the *default* -- it's not mandatory. To use BibTeX as the sorting tool, it's necessary to specify `backend=bibtex`.

Comment: Any news here? Did you get things up and running?

Comment: Any news here? Do thinks work now?