# Why doesn't biblatex work with BibTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

In this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401804/error-on-compiling-biblatex), people mention that `biblatex` requires `biber` to work. However, if `biblatex` has the option `backend=biber`, doesn't that mean that using `biber` is optional rather than mandatory?

Comment: There are several biblatex features that cannot be done with bibtex as the backend.

Comment: Ok, but then why is biber a biblatex option if it is actually mandatory?

Comment: I'm not saying it us mandatory, just that for many features it is required. Nowadays you only use the bibtex back end as a last measure. Someone wrote in another thread that bibtex can only do about 20% of what biber can. Not surprisingly, as biber is still being developed. But one should also remember that, if you are doing research, journals might not be able to handle biblatex content (due to how they operate internally), so pure bibtex (no biblatex) still has its uses.

Comment: You can do `backend=bibtex`, but you lose out on a lot of functionality. Some bibliography styles also require Biber nowadays.

Comment: In the specific situation of the question the user did not specify a `backend` option, so the default `backend=biber` is used. That setting requires Biber to be run and not BibTeX. Of course another solution would have been to tell the OP to use `backend=bibtex` and continue compiling with BibTeX. But BibTeX does not support all of  `biblatex`'s features and is considered a legacy backend. The `biblatex` documentation generally assumes Biber is used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Up until several (five or six?!) years ago, there was an age when the `biblatex` package was not yet as mature as it is now and the `biber` program was, ahem, less than perfectly stable and reliable. Understandably, the default back-end program (to perform *sorting*) was BibTeX. If one felt a bit adventurous and *wanted* to use `biber`, one could (and had to) specify `backend=biber` to override the default.

At some point, however, `biber` became the default back-end for `biblatex`, mainly because (a) it's much more powerful and versatile than BibTeX -- which is, after all, what `biber` was supposed to be all along -- and (b) `biber` eventually became sufficiently stable to be usable outside of, to put it delicately, experimental settings. Ever since this switch was made, it has technically speaking no longer been *necessary* to specify `backend=biber` if the intent is to use `biber` as the back-end. Conversely, if one nowadays really means to use BibTeX, one must specify `backend=bibtex` explicitly. A separate matter: there are by now some biblatex bibliography styles that *require* `biber`, i.e., they won't operate properly if BiBTeX is used.

As you probably know, though, old habits -- whether good or bad! -- are slow to die. Thus, many old hands, and quite few younger ones too, still write `backend=biber` even though it's no longer strictly necessary to do so if the plan is to use the program `biber`.

Comment: +1) You might want to mention that a while ago, `biblatex` was rewritten to make BibTeX a legacy backend (i.e. one that should not be used for new documents any more and is kept around mainly for backwards compatibility). The documentation now does not mention explicitly which features are Biber only any more, as it assumes that people use Biber.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks. I seem to remember that there was a real discussion at some point (roughly 5 to 6 years ago?) whether `biblatex` would even be made to work at all with BibTeX going forward, i.e., whether the option `backend=bibtex` would work at all. Thankfully (in my view; clearly, I don't claim to be speaking for anyone else...), though, the decision was made to preserve some backward compatibility -- in part, I suppose, to continue to be able to work with legacy documents. However, as you point out, for new bibliographies, the assumption should be that `biber` will be used.

Comment: +1 could change the bit about 'five or six years ago' to be an absolute reference?

Comment: @cmhughes - I'm afraid I haven't held on to the documentary evidence on this issue... (I.e., I'm pretty sure that it's more than 5 years ago, but less than about 7!) Feel free to undertake a thorough archeological dig. :-)

Comment: It doesn't worry me that much, but reading this in years hence will lead to different interpretations (e.g. Imagine reading it in 2022)

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402018), `biber` is the default choice for `backend` but one can also give `bibtex`. As already detailed, that choice was made as Biber offers more features than BibTeX. It is worth noting, however, that `biblatex` continues to allow the use of BibTeX as a back-end (there are no plans to remove the support). One factor in this is that `biblatex` was originally written to use BibTeX and that for quite a large number of 'simple' use cases (large parts of natural sciences, for example) the outcomes *are* equivalent to those for Biber.